# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PHPUnit 5.7.23

Tags: php, foreach, phpunit

Keep getting an error on *CodeWars* when im running the following code in *PHPUnit 5.7.23 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.*

**Error:** *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

**Code:**

```
if(is_array($no_dups)){
        foreach ($no_dups as $key => $value) {
            if ($value <= $t) {
                $limited[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

$no_dups is an array!

Also

```
if(is_array($no_dups)){
        foreach ($no_dups as $key => $value) {
            if ($value < $t) {
                $limited[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

returns no errors.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**After** some experimentation discovered that the error goes away if i remove the return statement at the end of the function is part of.

```
foreach ($no_dups as $key ) {  
        if ($value <= $t) {
                $limited[$key] = $value;
        }
    }   

    $final_three = array_slice($limited, -3, $k);

    $best = array_pop($final_three);

  return $best;

}
```

**Error**

```
foreach ($no_dups as $key ) {  
        if ($value <= $t) {
                $limited[$key] = $value;
        }
    }   

    $final_three = array_slice($limited, -3, $k);

    $best = array_pop($final_three);

  echo $best;
```

**gives No Error**

Comment: `foreach ($no_dups as $key) {`  does it give error when you do it like this as well? I am guessing your array structure is not like dictionary (as key-> value pairs) correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It eludes me how this has anything to do with PHPUnit, but PHPUnit 5 has been dead for years.

Comment: @Ali Beyit it appears to work ok just with $key

Comment: @Sebastian Bergman,  it works fine in my terminal. (not that it means anything)

Comment: Thank you Ali and Sebastian for taking the time to respond to my question :)